# Java Eclipse - Expect browser binary location

Tags: selenium, firefox, testing

I am trying to run the following Java Code:

```
package tests;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class sekcija9 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

I am using:

1. Firefox 62.0.2 64bit
2. Selenium 3.3.1
3. GeckoDriver 0.22.0 (latest)

I have looked here: [link](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/issues/676)

Do I need to downgrade Firefox version? If not, how can I resolve this issue without downgrade?

Comment: consider upgrading your selenium version. I'am using 3.14.0 and gecko driver .22.0 , and firefox Firefox 62.0.2 , and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and also check your firefox version is compatible with gecko drivers.

```
   import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   public class geckodriver {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
           Thread.sleep(5000);
//           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
//            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
//           
//           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

           capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
           capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
           capabilities.setVersion("your firefox version");
           capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
           capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false);

           WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver(capabilities);

             driver.get("http://www.google.com");

             Thread.sleep(5000);
             driver.quit();
}}
```

Comment: 64bit version of GeckoDriver.

Comment: Now it gives the following: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{moz:firefoxOptions={binary=Optional.empty, args=[], legacy=null, logLevel=null, prefs={}, profile=null}}]

Comment: You need to provide Firefox Binary location. Check out this link on how to set it up. :http://www.automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-0-launch-firefox-with-geckodriver/

Comment: Same as I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
```